# allow_url_fopen = 1 in php.ini is not working

Tags: php, cpanel

I am trying to upload file from my iPhone device. My `php` script for uploading file is this :

```
<?php
    $uploaddir = 'http://xxxxxxx.com/UploadImageInServer/'; 
    $file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']); 
    $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file; 
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        echo "Received file: $file"; 
    }
?>
```

But I am getting these warnings in my directory `error_log` file :

```
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 in /home/xxxx/public_html/UploadImageInServer/imageUpload.php on line 27
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(http://xxxx.com/UploadImageInServer/a.jpg): failed to open stream: no suitable wrapper could be found in /home/xxxx/public_html/UploadImageInServer/imageUpload.php on line 27
PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpKlBQI6' to 'http://xxxx.com/UploadImageInServer/a.jpg' in /home/xxxx/public_html/UploadImageInServer/imageUpload.php on line 27
```

Here line 27 is this : `if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile))`

So, After google, I found that I need to set `allow_url_fopen = 1` in `php.ini`.

With a `test.php` file in my remote directory by the below script I try to find out the location of my `php.ini` file and it's current state. Which give me this :

```
echo php_ini_loaded_file(); 

if( ini_get('allow_url_fopen') ) {
    echo "Yes";
} else {
    echo "No";
}
```

And the `echo` : `/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/etc/php.ini` & `No`.

Now I change my settings to **Show my hidden files**, and found no `php.ini` file there in `etc` folder. So I have created a new one and put this code there `allow_url_fopen = 1` and build my app from simulator.

But still getting those same warnings. I also move my `php.ini` file in my root directory and after build I am still getting those same warnings. So what am I doing wrong here? If you have a solution please share with me. A lot of Thanks in advance.

Have a nice day. :)

**P.S : My php version is 7.0**

Comment: `$uploadDir` needs to be a local directory, not a URL

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I want to upload my file to a remote directory. Not in local directory.

Comment: Then you can't use `move_uploaded_file`. PHP needs to know **how** to move your file to a remote directory (SCP, FTP, HTTP, etc). You can't just blindly write to a web-accessible URL, for obvious reasons.

Comment: You need to upload the file locally first, then you need to use some other method to upload the locally stored file to the other server...

Comment: Ok, In that case, what would be my local directory? If I use **$uploaddir = `uploads/`;** where will be the `uploads` folder? @iainn

Comment: It's relative to where your PHP script is running. If it's running in `/var/www/foo` and you specify *uploads/*, then it will attempt to move it to `/var/www/foo/uploads`. It's generally a better idea to specify an absolute path, using `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`/etc, to make it a bit more predicatable.

Comment: And why `php.ini` file always showing `NO`? Is there any thing I missing?

Comment: Ok, great. My `php` script is running on say `http://xxxxxxx.com/UploadImageInServer/` this directory. How could I relate this directory with your `/var/www/foo`? Pardon me, I am very late on server related topics. And with `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/etc` is it also a local directory? I really want to upload all my files in a fix folder say `UploadedImage` which is in my domain (Remote).